# Eclipse Paho MQTT client on Android, poor performance

Tags: android, performance, mqtt, paho

Im trying to use Eclipse Paho MQTT client on my Android app to receive MQTT messages.

Im receiving ~100 message/second, messages are fairly small (basically small json objects). These messages are coming from Mosquitto broker.

When I subscribe to MQTT topic, and start to receive messages, my Android app UI almost freezes. I do not even do anything about the received message on `messageArrived` callback.

My Eclipse Paho MQTT client usage is super basic, almost the same as in Eclipse Paho example.

Is Eclipse Paho MQTT client bad on performance, or is there something I might be doing wrong?

Im using:
`org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0` & `org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1`

**Update**

Below my actual code, which is part of the fragment. So in this test im just logging the received message topic. Also with out logging, I got same result, my app almost freezes.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1883", MqttClient.generateClientId());
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
            }
            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                Log.d("Mqtt", "messageArrived " + topic);
            }
            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);

        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    try {
                        mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("messages/#", 0);
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        Log.e("Mqtt", "subscribe error", exception);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.e("Mqtt", "Connection onFailure ", exception);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e("Mqtt", "error " + exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your actual code, especially the content of `messageArrived` callback

Comment: @hardillb I updated the original question to include my actual implementation.

Comment: Usually there are no slashes in front of MQTT topic names...

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderFarber I removed the leading slash (also updated the original question) but it seems that there is no difference in my android client performance.

Comment: I think the MqttAndroidClient communicates with the background service (which contains the actual client) using Intents(!) which are very CPU-intensive due to rights-management issues. What we would like to do is to not go via the extra service but implement our own... I'm thinking this might help, but I am not sure:
https://github.com/eladnava/paho-mqtt-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Paho Android Service is not using own thread to handle connection so everything is done in UI thread.

I ended up using Paho MqttAsyncClient, which handles connection in own tread its own.